# Interface name in front of method name meaning in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So I began to learn c# and specifically asp.net core and I came across a piece of code which I just can't understand what it means. I was reading docs to find some similar examples, but couldn't find anything.

```
public class Startup
{
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
        Configuration = configuration;
     }

     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

1. Why inside class `Startup` there is another keyword `Startup`? if that's a method, then why it starts with capital?
2. Why there is `IConfiguration` interface in front of `Configuration`? Shouldn't it be after, like `:IConfiguration`? And why is there empty body definition if it's not abstract function? Thanks.

Comment: This `public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)`  is the constructor of the class `Startup` and receives an object that implements the interface `IConfiguration`. This `public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }` is a property with a getter so client code can access the `IConfiguration` object.

Comment: I'd suggest googling 'what is a constructor C#' and 'what is a parameter C#' and 'what is a readonly property C#'. As is, I vote to close since your question is in fact multiple questions - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts . _This is not an attack on you - just that you should write multiple questions to avoid the 'Person A writes a good answer to the first question and Person B writes a good answer to the second question' problem. If they are separate questions, you can pick the best answer for the two questions independently._

Comment: See some c# [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/)

Comment: [Constructors docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Comment: I think a more effective way to learn C# (or any language) would be to start with [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/index) or a book rather than diving into code and asking "What's this?  What's that?"  You'll have a hard time searching for or asking about these concepts (as we see here) if you don't know what they're called, and the fact that these are such really, really basic concepts in C# suggests you're trying to (and, no offense, failing to) learn in the wrong direction, working _backwards_ from code instead of _forwards_ from concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the constructor, it's called when you use `new Startup()`

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

This is an autoproperty, it returns `IConfigruation` and automatically implements a property `Getter`

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```